# DNS config issue: Too few IPv4 name servers (1)

Tags: domain-name-system, vps

I have run a pingdom dns check on my website offerteinternet.net, here is the page for reference: http://dnscheck.pingdom.com/?domain=offerteinternet.net.

The error I am having is that I have only one IPv4 name server, while I should actually have two in place:

ns1.v00h2l-gsv.sphostserver.com
ns2.v00h2l-gsv.sphostserver.com

On another test I did here http://cloudmonitor.ca.com/en/dnstool.php?vhost=_&vtt=1377078007&varghost=offerteinternet.net&vaction=trace&trace=analyse the nameserver ns1.v00h2l-gsv.sphostserver.com gives a fatal response.

The same thing happens with other websites/domains hosted on the same VPS (Centos 6 + WHM/cPanel + Varnish). **What is causing the issue?**

Moreover the SOA returns an error when trying to deliver email to the owner. This is actually due to the fact that my address is surname.name@gmail.com, but on the SOA record it actually reads surname.name.gmail.com (which is the correct syntax) and when trying to interprete the address the system puts the @ in the wrong place, making it surname@name.gmail.com. **Is this even a problem to worry about?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like **ns1.v00h2l-gsv.sphostserver.com** and **ns2.v00h2l-gsv.sphostserver.com** point to the same IP address (in fact the same IP address as **offerteinternet.net**). The reason two (or more) **separate** nameservers are suggested is to improve availability by providing redundancy.

If both entries end up on the same IP address, and there is a routing problem to that IP address, then you lose the ability to do DNS lookups for your zone.

For the email address in the SOA entry, you have two options:

1. Gmail specifically ignores dots in usernames, so **first.last@gmail.com** is the same as **firstlast@gmail.com**. So the simplest thing to do would be to remove the first dot in your SOA email, i.e. make it `firstlast.gmail.com`, because it will still end up in your inbox
2. Escape the dot in your username with a slash, e.g. `first\.last.gmail.com`

Note that the Gmail behaviour in 1. is not universal - you can't assume it works if you move to a different mail server

Comment: ....IIRC shouldn't the email address in the zone file end in a '.' if it's canonical?

Comment: Thanks @jjv . So, what would the best practice be? Is there a way to clone DNS zones so that they stay updated overtime? Or should I manage them myself?

Comment: The best practice is separate nameservers, ideally on separate networks. You can keep them sync'd using AXFR (zone transfer), or some other mechanism. Personally I think the easiest way is to just pay a service to do it (DNS Made Easy, Amazon Route 53, Zonomi etc) and rely on their redundancy.

Answer (score 1):

Currently ns1.v00h2l-gsv.sphostserver.com and ns2.v00h2l-gsv.sphostserver.com points to the same ip address, which strongly implies that they are hosted on the same server, which kind of negates the point of having two nameservers.